# I try to load a CSV file from my local machine to IBM Cloud db2 but I face this error continuously

Tags: db2, cloud, ibm-cloud, concourse

Failed to upload file. The AWS Access Key ID you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: eea5dbcc-67a3-4d4b-a36f-16ebf7f055ae; S3 Extended Request ID: null)

or

HWCCON0006E: An unexpected error occurred when calling restAPI http://middle-end.icd-control.svc.cluster.local:8080/v4/ibm/deployments/crn%3Av1%3Aibm%3Alocal%3Adashdb-for-transactions%3Aus-south%3Aa%2F6ffa17fcf55f41cf9c082c34e772b17c%3Ab0aebb68-94fa-46ec-a1fc-1c999edb6187%3A%3A. Please retry later. If this error persists, please record the operation procedure and report to your console administrator.

I'm doing data engineering course from CourseEra and enrolled in IBM data enginnering course "Introduction to Data Engineering". While attending a lab, I try to load a CSV file from my local machine to IBM Cloud db2 but I face this error continuously.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have an aws account ?
2. Create an access key on your user ( not the root user, root user is the user with the account email )
3. install awscli on your local machine .
4. configure awscli ,with `aws configure`
5. try again.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the same error when trying to upload local CSV file to IBM cloud DB2 database. It seems to be a kind of system error, unrelated to what you're specifically doing. AWS account is irrelevant there, both you and me are trying to upload local CSV data file to IBM cloud database, if I understand right. Just to be sure this is the situation, please re-check you picked up "Local Computer" as a source for the data, and not "AWS S3".
[IBM UI Data load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz3W0.png)

Comment: I opened a support ticket at IBM Cloud and the issue was fixed.
I've just tried to load the CSV data to the table and it works.